# how to force branch in git extensions to set head to location

Tags: git, git-extensions

In git extensions, I have checked out the branch I need, the problem is that the head of the branch is below my last commit. If I right click and hit reset current branch to here, it shows like it has changed the branch to the location - but if I check out another branch then go back, it's like nothing was done and the head of the branch will not go up to include my last commit. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean github extensions? Are you talking about Git Extensions?

Comment: yes, git extensions, sorry. I believe i have rebased the head properly now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, for instance, in [this article](http://www.trinitycore.info/How-to%3aWin):

> Includes [Git Extension](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/), [MySYSGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/), and [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) - be sure to install all three

That way, you cann fallback to the command-line interface and see if your "Git Extension" command has worked or not.

Regarding reset, check if you see a sub-option "Reset current branch to here -> **Hard**", because that would effectively reset the HEAD to you more recent commit.
However, use it with caution as it would also reset the index and the working tree (any current modification would be removed, as in "erased").